# JOOQ and Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, jooq

Has anyone tried using JOOQ with the Spring framework or am I breaking new ground?

http://www.jooq.org

Comment: As jOOQ is quite new itself, you're likely to break new ground. How would you like to interface the two libraries? Are you planning to use spring as a means to configure jOOQ? I'm curious about your use-case

Comment: Hi Lukas, I don't have a particular use case in mind. I asked the question to see if others have used the two libraries together and have any experiences worth sharing. I can see that I can use a Spring configured data source to provide a connection to the jOOQ factory. Beyond that I'm not sure if there is any merit in deeper integration but I'm a relative novice to Spring so favour learning by example.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Many people are using jOOQ with Spring or Spring Boot

- https://www.baeldung.com/jooq-with-spring
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-support-for-jooq

There is also a very good tutorial by Petri Kainulainen, explaining every step to set up a project, here:

- [Using jOOQ with Spring: Configuration](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/jooq/using-jooq-with-spring-configuration/)
- [Using jOOQ with Spring: Code Generation](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/jooq/using-jooq-with-spring-code-generation/)
- [Using jOOQ with Spring: CRUD](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/jooq/using-jooq-with-spring-crud/)
- [Using jOOQ with Spring: Sorting and Pagination](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/jooq/using-jooq-with-spring-sorting-and-pagination/)

Here's a blog post about how to use jOOQ with Spring Boot, especially useful when you need the commercial distributions of jOOQ:

- https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-use-jooqs-commercial-distributions-with-spring-boot/

Answer (score 17):

I was looking to use jOOQ as an builder library for providing queries to Spring's JdbcTemplate and related classes. Unfortunately, jOOQ appears to combine two concepts into the same set of classes: SQL generation and query execution.  In my case, I want the former but want to let Spring handle the latter.  It does work, though.  For example, you can do something like this (using jOOQ 2.x API):

```
Factory create = new Factory(null, SQLDialect.ORACLE);
getJdbcTemplate().query(
    create.select(create.field(ID_COL),
                  create.field(VALUE_COL))
        .from(FOO_TABLE)
        .where(create.field(ID_COL).equals("ignored"))
        .getSQL(),
    myRowMapper,
    id);
```

Comment: That's a nice example of integration. Why did you choose spring to execute your query? Because of jOOQ's missing row-mapping functionality? Or the lack of transaction handling?

Comment: @LukasEder For me its transaction handling. I use AspectJ + Spring extensively (sorry for the stalking... just happend to hit another Q. answered by you).

Comment: @AdamGent: Spring's transaction handling can be used along with jOOQ's query execution. This has been proven on the jOOQ user group. There should be a section in the manual about this, though...

Comment: @LukasEder in theory it seems very possible. One could just make try...catch exception decorator around your Factories and translate them to Spring Exceptions (which are used for Transaction management). Can you add a link to this posting as it would seem useful for the OP.

Comment: @AdamGent: Or just hook an [`ExecuteListener`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html) into jOOQ, that takes care of translating jOOQ's `DataAccessException` into whatever Spring exception you need... That should take about 5-10 lines of code. See the [docs here](http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.5/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/)

Comment: Done read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12326885/318174 and see it here: https://gist.github.com/3669307

Answer (score 9):

getting spring transactions running with jOOQ is a lot simpler (unless I forgot something):

just wrap your data source into

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy
```

**optional**: to delay opening a jdbc connection until the first actual sql statement happens use

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy
```

so as an sample do this to create a jOOQ factory with 'transactions' and 'lazyness' applied

```
DataSource rawDS = /* your actual data source */
// (optional) make access lazy
final DataSource lazyDS = new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(rawDataSource);
// make spring transactions available in plain jdbc context
final DataSource txDS = new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(lazyDS);
// create jOOQ factory
Factory jooq = new Factory(txDS, /* dialect */, /* settings */)
// voila!
```

Comment: a small github repo with working demo would be a great help !

Answer (score 7):

All you need to do/know to make jOOQ work with spring:

1. Get the `java.sql.Connection` bound to the thread by the transaction manager.
2. Handle transactions properly through exception translation
3. Understand that the jOOQ **Factory** objects (despite the name) are not threadsafe. and thus will require instantiating a new object per use (Do not do this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10040078/318174)).

So for the first and second case I offer this gist: https://gist.github.com/3669307 which does what [Lukas recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474365/jooq-and-spring#comment16531046_6796688).

For the third case you can either create basically a factory of a factory (which contains the `DataSource`) or just instantiate a new `Factory` object in each method using the wired `DataSource` in your spring component.

```
@Service
public class MyDaoOrService {
    @Autowired
    private void DataSource dataSource;

    @Transactional
    public void doSomeJooq(){
        Settings s = new Settings();
        //You could instead put this jooq configuration xml
         s.getExecuteListeners().add("com.snaphop.jooq.SpringExceptionTranslationExecuteListener");
        MyGeneratedFactory f = new MyGeneratedFactory(dataSource, s);
        f.select(); //etc
    }
}
```

As for the settings listener you can JOOQ's configuration support to avoid the programmatic creation.

I won't cover how you setup a `DataSource` in Spring as that is covered in myriad of other/better places.

Comment: This answer uses jOOQ 2.x API. I think that's worth mentioning, or changing API usage to 3.x...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Spring to build a webapp, you probably want to be doing something like this:

```
try {
  Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
  try {
    // Do something with JOOQ
    // No need to use a JdbcTemplate!
  }
  finally {
    if (conn != null) {
      conn.close();
    }
  }
} catch (SQLException e) {
  // your error handling
}
```

You probably want to be getting a DataSource via Spring's dependency injection, because your web container, Tomcat or whathaveyou, is providing the DataSource and doing connection pooling. In one of your spring config files you would have something like

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/datasource"/>
```

The object that the above code is in (or some object that provides this code with the datasource) could have configuration in a spring file to instantiate it with the datasource, like

```
<bean id="fooService" class="com.fubar.FooServiceImpl">
  <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</bean>
```

The portion of the string "jdbc/datasource" would correspond to a resource name configured in the web container. This varies, but for Tomcat it might be a context file  in conf/Catalina/localhost under Tomcat home, for example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context debug="10" reloadable="true" useNaming="true" antiJARLocking="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/datasource" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        username="foo" password="fubar" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" 
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/foobase"/>         
</Context>
```

Comment: Why do your own connection handling when JdbcTemplate can do it for you in fewer lines with less risk of getting it wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will be helpful for someone....

Spring application context configuration.

```
 <bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName">
            <value>SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE</value>
        </property>
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment">
            <value type="boolean">true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="dataSource" 
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" 
        value="jdbc:h2://${user.home}
        ${file.separator}tracciabilitaCanarini${file.separator}db${file.separator}basedb"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value="sa"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="datasourceConnection" 
     class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean" 
      lazy-init="true" depends-on="dataSource">
        <property name="targetObject">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="targetMethod">
            <value>getConnection</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="publicFactory" class="dbLayer.db.PublicFactory" lazy-init="true"
      depends-on="datasourceConnection" >
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="datasourceConnection"  />
    </bean>
```

It will auto fill the public factory with the given connection (and yes, it can be a pooled connection, with auto close etc., see DriverManagerDataSource class for more detailed configuration).
And now, the publicFactory. Note: no need to modify the original public factory generated by jOOQ.

```
/**
 * This class is generated by jOOQ
 */
package dbLayer.db;

/**
 * This class is generated by jOOQ.
 */
@javax.annotation.Generated(value    = {"http://www.jooq.org", "2.0.5"},
                            comments = "This class is generated by jOOQ")
public class PublicFactory extends org.jooq.util.h2.H2Factory {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1930298411;

    /**
     * Create a factory with a connection
     *
     * @param connection The connection to use with objects created from this factory
     */
    public PublicFactory(java.sql.Connection connection) {
        super(connection);
    }

    /**
     * Create a factory with a connection and some settings
     *
     * @param connection The connection to use with objects created from this factory
     * @param settings The settings to apply to objects created from this factory
     */
    public PublicFactory(java.sql.Connection connection, org.jooq.conf.Settings settings) {
        super(connection, settings);
    }
}
```

At the end, simply call the factory.

```
 PublicFactory vs = (PublicFactory) SpringLoader.getBean("publicFactory");
    SimpleSelectQuery<VersionRecord> sq = vs.selectQuery(dbLayer.db.tables.Version.VERSION);
    VersionRecord v = null;
                try {
                    v = sq.fetchAny();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.warn("Seems that version table does not exists!", e);
                }
```

Done!

Comment: **!!!!!** This is a very bad idea. Spring generally assumes the beans it creates are singletons and thus threadsafe. **PublicFactory is not threadsafe!** You need to mark your [bean as scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-scopes) correctly for this to work and even if you do I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

For Java configuration (which is default for Spring Boot) you can use the following code:

```
/* JOOQ Configuration */
@Bean
public DataSourceConnectionProvider dataSourceConnectionProvider() {
    return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(dataSource());
}

@Bean
public DefaultConfiguration defaultConfiguration() {
    DefaultConfiguration defaultConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();
    defaultConfiguration.setConnectionProvider(dataSourceConnectionProvider());
    defaultConfiguration.setSQLDialect(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
    return defaultConfiguration;
}

@Bean
public DSLContext dslContext() {
    return new DefaultDSLContext(defaultConfiguration());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way,(I have found) to use Spring Transactions with jOOQ, is given here: http://blog.liftoffllc.in/2014/06/jooq-and-transactions.html

Have a look at this answer for better explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24380508/542108

Comment: Link-only answers are bad as the links will rot.