# Spring JDBC's transactions handling doesn't work with Google Guice

Tags: java, transactions, guice, spring-jdbc, jooq

I use Google Guice and [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) in my project. Currently I decided to introduce transaction handling using Spring JDBC.

So I did the following.

I set a data source and a transaction manager in Guice module.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
DataSource provideDataSource(IExternalSettings settings) {
    Jdbc3PoolingDataSource dataSource = new Jdbc3PoolingDataSource();
    // configuring DataSource
    return dataSource;
}


@Provides
@Singleton
DataSourceTransactionManager provideDataSourceTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource));
}
```

Then I inject my transaction manager to a persistence facade

```
@Inject
public PersistenceFacade(final DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    this.dataSource = transactionManager.getDataSource();
    this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
}
```

Later, I use this data source to create jOOQ factory: `new Factory(dataSource, ...)`.

Finaly I run my database access code:

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
TransactionStatus transaction = transactionManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition);
try {
    // db code in transaction
    transactionManager.commit(transaction);
    return result;
} catch (Exception e) {
    transactionManager.rollback(transaction);
    throw e;
}
```

So far, so good. It **works as expected**.

So, my next step is to introduce `@Transactional` annotation using Guice AOP. I created an interceptor

```
class TransactionalMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    @Inject
    private DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Override
    public Object invoke(final MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        DefaultTransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        TransactionStatus transaction = transactionManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition);
        try {
            Object result = invocation.proceed();
            transactionManager.commit(transaction);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transactionManager.rollback(transaction);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

And configured it in `configure()` method of Guice module:

```
TransactionalMethodInterceptor transactionalMethodInterceptor = new TransactionalMethodInterceptor();
requestInjection(transactionalMethodInterceptor);
bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(Transactional.class), transactionalMethodInterceptor);
```

And now **the issues begin**. I can see, using debugger, that control flow reaches interceptor. In particular, it reaches `transactionManager.rollback(...)` invocation. But the transaction is **not actually roll backed**.

I have no clue what's the reason. Any ideas? I'll be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: How does the instance, on which the invocation.proceed() is called, get the transaction?

Comment: @AlenVrečko, Interceptor has a transactionManager injected. It uses it to get a new transaction. Not sure if it answers your question?

Comment: Let me put it this way, does getConnection return the same connection inside your transactional block?

Comment: I don't call `getConnection()` explicitly. I pass a data source to jOOQ's factory and it gets the connection. However, it does the same in both cases (ie. with and without AOP).

Comment: What's the `Exception e` that leads to the control flow executing a `rollback()`?

Comment: Hi, @LukasEder, tx for commenting! The exception is `org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [/* my SQL */]; ERROR: null value in column "salt" violates not-null constraint`. This SQL tries to insert a row to a different table. It's a 2nd query in the transaction. I'm passing it a `null` to make sure it rolls back properly.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping to see some good reason there, for the rollback not to be executed. Maybe you have accidentally nested two `@Transactional` methods, without properly handling this case?

Comment: Why aren't you using Spring's `TransactionInterceptor`?

Comment: @BenManes, does the interceptor yield me any advantages? I'm keen on giving it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to come back to this one and I think I found a solution.

First of all, I need to mention I introduced a bit of misunderstanding, when I said it all works without AOP. Today I couldn't reproduce it and I noticed that the connection that is rolled back is different than the one that jOOQ is using. So Alan Vrecko (see comment above) was right!

Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474365/jooq-and-spring/12326885#12326885) and [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/agentgt/3669307). I decided to give them a try and it worked! However, it appeared that all previous steps are valid and still need to be there (including Google Guice's interceptor).

The only I change I had to introduce was to remove `DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, dataSource);` from `SpringExceptionTranslationExecuteListener. exception(ExecuteContext ctx)`. So finally the method looks like

```
@Override
public void exception(ExecuteContext ctx) {
    SQLException ex = ctx.sqlException();
    Statement stmt = ctx.statement();
    Connection con = ctx.getConnection();
    DataSource dataSource = ctx.getDataSource();
    JdbcUtils.closeStatement(stmt);
    ctx.exception(getExceptionTranslator(dataSource).translate("jOOQ", ctx.sql(), ex));
}
```

Then all seems to work properly. Thank you all for comments. Of course I'm still open to new/better solutions.